# Replacing characters in a string if they match a hashtable and looping down the stirng

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is where I am at now:

```
CharList = []
text = "xxxxAAaaaSSSxxx"
PasswordSubHT = {"a":"@" , "A":"4" , "S":"5"}
for LETTER in text:
    CharList.append(LETTER)
for EL in CharList:
    if EL in PasswordSubHT:
        print(text.replace(EL,str(PasswordSubHT[EL])))
```

This is what I get:

```
xxxx44aaaSSSxxx
xxxx44aaaSSSxxx
xxxxAA@@@SSSxxx
xxxxAA@@@SSSxxx
xxxxAA@@@SSSxxx
xxxxAAaaa555xxx
xxxxAAaaa555xxx
xxxxAAaaa555xxx
```

This is what I am trying to get:

```
xxxx4AaaaSSSxxx
xxxx44aaaSSSxxx
xxxxAA@aaSSSxxx
xxxxAA@@aSSSxxx
xxxxAA@@@SSSxxx
```

I want to do substitution down character by charter which is why I am piping the string to an array. Is this the right way to go about this?

Comment: In the third line of your expected output, why do the elements switch back to `"A"`

Answer (score 2):

Python string [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method replaces all the instance of the letter with the new letter in the string. For example in the first pass, it skips all letters until A, then sees that A is in the Sub List and replaces ALL INSTANCES of A in the string with 4. Then it moves to the next character, which at that point has become 4 instead of A.
Python strings are immutable. So you cant really pick them up and change letters in between.
What you can do is convert this string into a list. `char_list = list(text)`. Then you can iterate this and keep a counter.

```
for char in char_list:
   counter = counter + 1
   if char in PassSubList:
      char_list[counter] = PassSubList[char]
 return_list = ''.join(char_list)
```

Comment: This is not totally right. `replace` has a third argument `count` which you can set to 1 and just replace the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Check this and let me know:

```
text = "xxxxAAaaaSSSxxx"
PasswordSubHT = {"a":"@" , "A":"4" , "S":"5"}

for letter in text:
    if letter in PasswordSubHT.keys():
        text = text.replace(letter, str(PasswordSubHT[letter]))
        print(text)
```

Note:
`replace(x, y)` will replace all the `x` in the text. If you want to replace just one char at the time add the `count` argument = 1: `text = text.replace(letter, str(PasswordSubHT[letter]), 1)`

Comment: Same result. I was playing with enumerate trying to see if that helped at all.

Comment: Try the: `text = text.replace(letter, str(PasswordSubHT[letter]), 1)` it will just replace the first occurrence. Check my note.

Comment: Good call! I must have missed that in the documentation.

Comment: The answer given by paradox is not right, `replace(x, y, count)` does replace all occurrences by default but you can set `count` to the number of times you want to replace the char.

Comment: Also check that you don't need to loop over the text to create the char list. You can loop directly over the text and work with the chars. So the first loop in your code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question, there is an important thing you need to know about Python strings, which is that they are immutable.

As the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types) doc proposes:

> The value of some objects can change. Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable.

So you can't just use the `replace method` but you have to reassign the new string into your `text` string.

So this part:

```
print(text.replace(EL,str(PasswordSubHT[EL])))
```

Would be:

```
text = text.replace(LETTER, PasswordSubHT[LETTER], 1)
print(text)
```

You don't also have to loop over the string to assign it to a list, but just loop over the string itself and check the condition you want.

According to [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) method doc. You can specify how many characters are allowed to be replaced, by providing the `maxreplace` argument. So what you need is something like:

```
CharList = []
text = "xxxxAAaaaSSSxxx"
PasswordSubHT = {"a":"@" , "A":"4" , "S":"5"}
for LETTER in text:
    if LETTER in PasswordSubHT.keys():
        # Note: Check the new max character argument.
        text = text.replace(LETTER, PasswordSubHT[LETTER], 1)
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
text = "xxxxAAaaaSSSxxx"
PasswordSubHT = {"a":"@" , "A":"4"}
combos = {a:iter([b*i for i in range(1, len(re.findall(a, text))+1)]) for a, b in PasswordSubHT.items()}
new_results = [[re.sub('{}+'.format(i), next(combos[i[0]])+i[c:], text) for c, i in enumerate(b)] for b in re.findall('|'.join(map(lambda x:'{}+'.format(x), PasswordSubHT.keys())), text)]
final_results = [i for b in new_results for i in b]
```

Output:

```
['xxxx4AaaaSSSxxx', 'xxxx44aaaSSSxxx', 'xxxxAA@aSSSxxx', 'xxxxAA@@SSSxxx', 'xxxxAA@@@SSSxxx']
```